# Killing a tick - ListPlot

Tags: plotting, ticks

Consider this code

```
ticks = StringJoin /@ 
 Map[ToString, RandomChoice[{a, 1, b, 2}, {64, 4}], {2}];

rotatedTicks = Rotate[#, Pi/2] & /@ ticks; 

numberedTicks  = Transpose[{Range[64], rotatedTicks}];

numbers = RandomReal[1, 64];

ListPlot[numbers, Filling -> Axis, Ticks -> {numberedTicks}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

It produces an extra annoying tick on the y axis (`122a` in this run). How can I kill it?

[image]

Comment: Please don't treat [ticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick) yourself, go see a doctor and get it removed :D (sry, couldn't resist)

Comment: If you do not want the `Ticks` on y-axis at all, just do `Ticks -> {numberedTicks,None}` or just use `Automatic`: `Ticks -> {numberedTicks,Automatic}`

Comment: This is explained in the first few lines under "Details" in the docs for [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, your Ticks apply to both the x and y axis. The only substitution that can be made using these tick rules is for the value 1 on your range.

To leave the y axis alone you can set the ticks to default or sub in your own new rules:

```
ListPlot[numbers, Filling -> Axis, 
 Ticks -> {numberedTicks, Automatic}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
ListPlot[
  numbers,  
  Filling -> Axis, Ticks -> {numberedTicks, None}, ImageSize -> Large 
  ]
```

*Note:* `numberedTicks` as in original post.

**Output**

[image: output]

**Reference**

[Ticks](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html)